# How to determine whether a polygon is inside other one?

Tags: python, svg, polygon

I have a simple example ([SVG source](http://pastie.org/3732822)) looks like you can see below. The **path** with id "**rect2816**" described in **d** attribute:

```
m 140.53571,188.625 0,148.1875 273.9375,0 0,-148.1875 -273.9375,0 z 
m 132.25,42.03125 c 3.64586,0.0236 7.47296,0.12361 11.5,0.28125 36.65941,1.43507 57.84375,15.88072 57.84375,32.84375 0,7.41614 -1.94981,21.58652 -13.28125,24.09375 -14.58711,3.2276 -40.46224,-5.35276 -53.125,6.625 -26.65285,25.21104 -48.00843,-19.04537 -57.875,-32.84375 -12.16196,-17.00847 0.24962,-31.35357 54.9375,-31 z
```

Here, the first line describes parent polygon, the second - the hole (as you can see). But How can I find this hole program way? I'm using Python. Maybe there is some library for easy solution?

[image: A polygon inside other polygon]

Comment: One possibility is to see if every vertex of the second polygon is inside the first polygon and that no edges of the second polygon cross the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the paths into (x,y) pairs and apply this function for each point of the second polygon.

```
# determine if a point is inside a given polygon or not
# Polygon is a list of (x,y) pairs.

def point_inside_polygon(x,y,poly):

n = len(poly)
inside =False

p1x,p1y = poly[0]
for i in range(n+1):
    p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
    if y > min(p1y,p2y):
        if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
            if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                if p1y != p2y:
                    xinters = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                if p1x == p2x or x <= xinters:
                    inside = not inside
    p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y

return inside
```

Source:
http://www.ariel.com.au/a/python-point-int-poly.html

Comment: To transform an arbitrary path into a polygon, see http://phrogz.net/svg/convert_path_to_polygon.xhtml

Comment: @mihai the link you provided is no longer available

Comment: @FedericaTomola I updated the answer to include the code, the original page can still be found on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20140301111830/http://www.ariel.com.au/a/python-point-int-poly.html

Answer (score 1):

Not so much of a Pythonic answer, but a geometrical-algorithmical:

Polygon B is inside of polygon A iff each corner of B and each edge of B is completely inside polygon A.

To find whether a corner (a point) is inside a polygon, a simple approach is to bite off so-called "ears" off the polygon.  An "ear" is a convex corner, and biting it off means to simply remove this corner.  With each biting act, check whether the point is inside the ear (the triangle you bit off).  (There's mathematical proof that for each loopless polygon you can find at least two such ears (convex corners).)

To find whether an edge of B is completely inside A means you have to find out whether the edge is cutting any edge of polygon A.

Of course, if both polygons are completely convex, you don't have to check the edges at all.

That's a straight-forward approach without the details on the basic geometric checks you will have to perform.  But maybe it helps you.

Comment: **mihai** gave me Pythonic implementation of your suggestion. Thank you!