# Select SVG elements by making a free-hand drawing around them

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am working on a project where I want to draw a line around some SVG elements in order to make a selection of the objects inside the area.

Here is a screenshot of what I have right now. I have used Paint to add the line in order to make it perfectly clear what I am trying to achieve. I want to select the two `rect` inside the drawn circle.

[image: Screenshot]

I see a number of steps that has to be solved:

1. Create a `path` element at `mousedown` and record the mouse movements until `mouseup`
2. Close the `path`, in case the user didn't draw a circle
3. Find svg elements that is completely or partly inside the circle

Which approaches do you see, and do you have any recommendations on how to go about it?

I am using [D3.js](https://d3js.org/). This [slide](https://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/ribbon.html) (by Mike Bostock, the creator of D3) might be interesting to take a look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go the following steps:

1. getting the aabb (or min/max box) of the freehand form,
2. finding all elements whose aabb overlaps the freeforms' one and save the in a list,
3. getting the convex hull of freehand form,
4. test if each or some of the vertices from the elements of the list lie inside the convex-hull

Depending if you test all vertices to lie inside the convex hull you can determine if the element lies fully inside the freehand drawing or just overlaps it.

Unfortunately I am not that familiar with d3.js, but just guess that it provides methods to gain convex hulls, aabbs and test points to be inside a polygon. Probably it even provides you with the ability to make aabb queries to find overlapping aabb in step 2.

good luck...

Comment: Yeah, something like that should work. You may find the answers here useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029139/how-to-determine-whether-a-polygon-is-inside-other-one

Comment: +1 For introducing me to the concept of a convex hull. Cue 2hrs of non work-related wikipedia trawling...

Comment: Thank you @philipp. I am not familiar with the concept of aabb, so I will look into that. It sounds like a good approach.